# Mudar visibilidade

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Como faço pra mudar a visibilidade de um layout que esta em uma outra activity?
Quero fazer isso ao clicar em uma imagem.. sei usar o método *onClick*.
só falta a imaginação de como alterar a visibilidade em tempo de execução.

Já tentei:

```
activityB B = new activityb();
B.layQueroEsconder.setVisible(GONE);
```

Quando coloco isso no `onCreate` da minha `activityA` o *apk* nem abre.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, na minha activityB onde estava o layout a ser escondido, usei :

```
layQueroEsconder.setVisibility(layQueroEsconder.getVisibility() ^ View.GONE);
```

Usando o operardor `"^" XOR` ele inverteu a visibilidade.